# Which MySQL connection is better to use with C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

Should I use the native .NET connector for MySQL?  Or should I use the ODBC connector for MySQL and use that ODBC connection in C#?  I am using C# 2010 Express.  Which one is easier to manipulate data in a MySQL database?

Comment: I don't consider this a full answer, but I suggest avoiding ODBC for now.

Comment: As an additional partial answer, I'll mention that if you stick to the IDBReader family of interfaces instead of concrete classes, you'll be able to change your mind if your initial guess turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I would go with the .NET MySql Connector, that would be like using the OleDb one for Oracle (while it can be done why not use the proper tool for the job)